# Trying to get GameObject to be created using variables from list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a GameObject to be created by inputting the TileID.
For my Terrain Generation I'd eventually like to be able to do something like

```
Generate()
{
    Tile(<TileID>); 
}
```

Right now It will only generate a Stone tile for me since its the second of two items in the list. What can I do to allow myself to input the TileID to display the right tile.

TileObject Class:

```
public class TileObject : MonoBehaviour {
//Instance Variables
TileManager tileManager;
GameObject gameManager;

//Variables

public int TileID;
Sprite TileSprite;
string TileName;
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    gameManager = GameObject.Find("Manager");
    tileManager = gameManager.GetComponent<TileManager>();
    spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    foreach (Tile tile in tileManager.Tiles)
    {
        TileID = tile.tileID;
        TileSprite = tile.tileSprite;
        TileName = tile.tileName;
    }
}
public TileObject(int TileID) 
{

    gameObject.name = TileName;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = TileSprite;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

}
```

Tile Class:

```
public Tile(int newTileID, string newTileName, Sprite newTileSprite, float newBreakSpeed) 
{
    tileID = newTileID;
    tileName = newTileName;
    tileSprite = newTileSprite;
    breakSpeed = newBreakSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tileManager should instantiate new tiles. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject tilePrefab;

    [Serializable]
    public class Tile {
        public int tileID;
        public string tileName;
        public Sprite tileSprite;
        public float breakSpeed;
    }

    // List should be populated in inspector
    public List<Tile> Tiles;

    public GameObject Generate(int id) {
        GameObject newObj = null;
        try {

            var data = Tiles.FirstOrDefault(tileData => id == tileData.tileID);
            newObj = Instantiate(tilePrefab);
            newObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = data.tileSprite;
            newObj.name = data.tileName; // same name to multiple tiles?
        } catch {
            Debug.LogWarning("TileManager not initialised properly!");
        }
        return newObj;
    }
}
```

The tilePrefab is a game object that is used as "prototype" for instantiation. In this example it is just a 2d sprite.
[image: tile image]

the tileManager tile data is populated in the inspector:
[image: tile manager image]

then you can generate tiles with:

```
    var manager = GetComponent<TileManager>();
    // generate 10 tiles with id [0..maxid]
    int tilecount = 10;
    int maxid = 1;
    for (int id = 0; id <= maxid; ++id) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tilecount; ++i) {
            var obj = manager.Generate(id);
            obj.transform.position = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I see here it appears as though you are trying to use a single TileObject when you should be using **one for each tile** you want to render.

Where are you calling the constructor for TileObject? If it is from within the TileManager class, including that would make answering this question a lot easier.

All I can say without a clear view of the TileManager class is that when the Start() method is called, while proceeding through your foreach you write over each previously set value for

```
TileID = tile.tileID;
TileSprite = tile.tileSprite;
TileName = tile.tileName;
```

So as it reads though the list of tiles in TileManager, the previously read tile information is overwritten. For Example...

Iteration 1

```
TileID = 0;
TileSprite = sprite1;
TileName = firstTile;
```

Iteration 2

```
TileID = 1;
TileSprite = sprite2;
TileName = secondTile;
```

Iteration 3

```
TileID = 2;
TileSprite = sprite3;
TileName = thirdTile;
```

After it reaches the end of the list (of size n) you will end up with

Iteration **N**

```
TileID = **N-1**;
TileSprite = sprite**N**;
TileName = **Nth**Tile;
```

Essentially the TileObject class will contain the values from the last tile in tileManager.Tiles. Then when you call TileObject() it is creating a tile using the values from the last tile in the list.

I can help lead you more in the correct direction once I have a copy of the TileManager class. Hopefully this helps, if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The TileManager Class contains just this one line `public List<Tile> Tiles = new List<Tile>();` Since I'm using unity public variables can be changed in the inspector. All of my tiles are added through the inspector.

Comment: How should I eliminate this overriding issue @DominSweet

Comment: Liam, in the 2nd answer on this thread @MikkoKoivisto does a fine job of giving an example of how this problem can be solved. I am not sure it is the best way but it is very similar in nature as to how I would solve this problem, so you can read his answer for further clarifications.